# How to see other WiFi network nodes by name (not IP)?

Tags: wireless-networking, dns

Right now my home network is a `TP Link` wifi router wired into a cable modem. I can see other nodes on the network (laptops, phones, thermostat, cameras etc) from one to another but only by IP address. Unfortunately, that changes and I would like to be able to see them by their fixed name. E.g. I am running an HTTP server on a laptop and I can see it from the phone by IP address but not by the host name.

Do I need to add some kind of DNS functionality to my rather basic wifi modem? I tried going into the admin dashboard but I couldn't find any section that would allow to do. The list of active clients on the dashboard does show the name but I cannot access it by name from another client.

Comment: Is your computer configured to use the router as its DNS server, or are you using something like 8.8.8.8 instead? Most home routers *do* have an internal DNS feature that's simply active the whole time, but it only works if you use it.

Comment: FYI, naming devices on a heterogeneous network has always been a huge mess. There have always been multiple competing protocols for name registration, assignment, and resolution. Many of those protocols allow multiple names per device, and different protocols have different rules for name length and valid character set. I don't think there are any modern best practices for taming the naming mess on either home or corporate networks. If you had a completely homogeneous network (all Macs, or all iPhones, or all Windows PCs, but not a mix) there would be solutions, but not for mixed networks.

Answer (score 0):

Check DHCP stats of your router. Sometimes DHCP clients provide names, sometime they don't. To get addressing by name working, your DHCP server on the router should be able to update DNS zone with provided leases, also you have to actually use that DNS server to get names resolved to IPs.